# Flutter container doesn't respond to gestures

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

If I have empty container with set width/height gesture detector doesn't work, but if I add something like color, it starts to work.

Test app:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  click(){
    _counter++;
    print('Clicked times: $_counter');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onTap: click,
          child: new Container(
            width: 50.0,
            height: 50.0,
            //color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

> Expected behavior is that gesture detector works when I set it's
>   child constraints. This is something that possibly happens with all
>   Widgets and other detectors.
>
> Simple use case example - I want to drag some Container that is lets
>   say width/height 4.0, but its too small, so I could embed that into
>   larger emptyContainer with with width/height 16.0 and center alignment
>   and could drag that one.
>
> Workaround: add transparent color.

**Logs**

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
>   Flutter (Channel master, v0.4.1-pre.25, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202,
>   locale en-US) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
>   (Android SDK 27.0.3) [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices
>   (Xcode 9.3) [✓] Android Studio (version 3.1) [!] IntelliJ IDEA
>   Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.2)
>       ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
>       ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. [✓] Connected devices (2 available)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: `GestureDetector` has an `onTap` property that you can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A container with bounds (height and width) without child is just a placeholder. So if you are wrapping it with `GestureDetector`, it will ignore the tap or touch because per official documentation of `GestureDetector` class, `By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches;`. That's the reason, the container won't respond to the touch / tap.

If you still want the empty container to respond to touch, you can use `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` property of `GestureDetector`.

Hope this answers your question.